# Store Uploaded File in MongoDB GridFS Using mgo without Saving to Memory

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

noob Golang and Sinatra person here.  I have hacked a Sinatra app to accept an uploaded file posted from an HTML form and save it to a hosted MongoDB database via GridFS.  This seems to work fine.  I am writing the same app in Golang using the mgo driver.

Functionally it works fine.  However in my Golang code, I read the file into memory and then write the file from memory to the MongoDB using mgo. This appears much slower than my equivalent Sinatra app.  I get the sense that the interaction between Rack and Sinatra does not execute this "middle" or "interim" step.

Here's a snippet of my Go code:

```go
func uploadfilePageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  // Capture multipart form file information
  file, handler, err := req.FormFile("filename")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  // Read the file into memory
  data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
  // ... check err value for nil

  // Specify the Mongodb database
  my_db := mongo_session.DB("... database name...")

  // Create the file in the Mongodb Gridfs instance
  my_file, err := my_db.GridFS("fs").Create(unique_filename)
  // ... check err value for nil

  // Write the file to the Mongodb Gridfs instance
  n, err := my_file.Write(data)
  // ... check err value for nil

  // Close the file
  err = my_file.Close()
  // ... check err value for nil

  // Write a log type message
  fmt.Printf("%d bytes written to the Mongodb instance\n", n)

  // ... other statements redirecting to rest of user flow...
}
```

**Question**:

- Is this "interim" step needed (`data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)`)?
- If so, can I execute this step more efficiently?
- Are there other accepted practices or approaches I should be considering?

Thanks...

Comment: It mainly depends on the mongodb driver you are using. I found this library that supports writing the files gradually, for example: http://godoc.org/github.com/sunfmin/tenpu/gridfs but I really don't know gridfs or what library you're using, so can't help much.

Comment: You said "This appears much slower than my equivalent Sinatra app.". I can't help you because I don't know anything about MongoDB. If you have an example demonstrating the speed difference between Sinatra and Go, I would love to see it however.

Comment: Eric... take a scan at my comments to Gustavo. The perception that the Go/mgo version of the code was slower was due to my flawed approach (reading the file contents in memory first).  In the Sinatra/Ruby Driver version, I don't explicitly take that step.  So the perceived slowness was an indication to me that I'm doing something inefficiently (rather than fundamental differences in execution speed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you should not read the file entirely in memory at once, as that will break when the file is too large. The second example in the [documentation for GridFS.Create](http://labix.org/v2/mgo#GridFS.Create) avoids this problem:

```
file, err := db.GridFS("fs").Create("myfile.txt")
check(err)
messages, err := os.Open("/var/log/messages")
check(err)
defer messages.Close()
err = io.Copy(file, messages)
check(err)
err = file.Close()
check(err)
```

As for why it's slower than something else, hard to tell without diving into the details of the two approaches used.

Comment: Gustavo thanks! This is definitely the direction I need to go.  No specific issues with execution speed.  The perception that the Go/mgo version was slower than Sinatra/Ruby Driver version was due to my flawed approach (i.e. reading the file into memory rather than opening the file and copying the contents to new GridFS file).  I assume I need to effectively "open" the file being posted via the multipart form and then copy it to the new GridFS file.  I will dig into the appropriate Go package to understand that a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the file from multipartForm, it can be saved into GridFs using below function. I tested this against huge files as well ( upto 570MB).

```
//....code inside the handlerfunc
for _, fileHeaders := range r.MultipartForm.File {
        for _, fileHeader := range fileHeaders {
            file, _ := fileHeader.Open()            
            if gridFile, err := db.GridFS("fs").Create(fileHeader.Filename); err != nil {
                //errorResponse(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            } else {
                gridFile.SetMeta(fileMetadata)
                gridFile.SetName(fileHeader.Filename)
                if err := writeToGridFile(file, gridFile); err != nil {
                    //errorResponse(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
                }
```

```
func writeToGridFile(file multipart.File, gridFile *mgo.GridFile) error {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    defer func() { file.Close() }()
    // make a buffer to keep chunks that are read
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        // read a chunk
        n, err := reader.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return errors.New("Could not read the input file")
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
        // write a chunk
        if _, err := gridFile.Write(buf[:n]); err != nil {
            return errors.New("Could not write to GridFs for "+ gridFile.Name())
        }
    }
    gridFile.Close()
    return nil
}
```