# how to upload pictures into mongodb using golang

Tags: mongodb, go, gridfs, mgo

Any ideas on how to upload picture files into Mongodb using Golang. I have done  research and I can find lots of examples with many diiferent languages, but none for Go. Any links for blogs or tutorials would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read some of the documentation on the [mgo](https://labix.org/mgo) driver.  Specifically under the gridfs section which covers how to store files in MongoDB.  Examples are also available on the mgo website.

Also similar questions have been asked on stack already such as: [Store Uploaded File in MongoDB GridFS Using mgo without Saving to Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159665/store-uploaded-file-in-mongodb-gridfs-using-mgo-without-saving-to-memory)